# capybara couldn't be installed due to nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capybara, nokogiri

i attached capybara to my Gemfile. when i bundle install, i always get this message

> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.3.1), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.

i realized that the problem with nokogiri gem, but i googled all the available methods to install it and that giving me the same output.

> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gem_make.out.

i wanna get the point of that error because a similar ones occurs frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, you need to reinstall libiconv even if it's already installed because *it may be missed or corrupted* .
then you can install nokogiri.

> brew tap homebrew/dupes.
>
> brew install libiconv.
>
> brew link libiconv --force.
>
> gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.3.1 -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local.